# Кастомизация балун-панели

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Нужно сделать кастомную балун-панель - убрать дефолтную кнопку "закрыть" и убрать белый фон панели.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаю балун через `templateLayoutFactory.createClass`, при открытии балуна указываю:

```
    {
contentLayout: balloonLayout,
panelMaxMapArea: Infinity
}
```

Можно ли прописать в стилях на странице что-то вроде

```
.ymaps-2-1-72-balloon_layout_panel {
background: transparent!important;
}

.ymaps-2-1-72-balloon__close-button {
    display: none!important;
}
```

или есть какое-нибудь решение получше?

Comment: разобрался с кнопкой закрытия- добавил опцию closeButton: false

Comment: Пример кастомного балуна из песочницы: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/balloon_autopan

Comment: из этого примера не понятно, как решить проблему

Comment: сейчас сделал так: при создании класса balloonLayout в методе build делаю следующее:

`
var container = this._$element;
                var parent1 = $(container).parent();
                parent1.css('cssText', 'background:transparent!important');
                var parent2 = $(parent1).parent();
                parent2.css('cssText', 'background:transparent!important;box-shadow:none!important;pointer-events:none!important');
`

но подозреваю, что это не идеальное решение

Comment: @Petr возможности кастомизировать балун-панель средствами API не завезли, поэтому тут или ваш вариант, или верстать макет балуна с нужным вам дизайном с нуля, как в примере выше (т. е. в таком случае обычный балун открываться на карте не будет, только панель).